# Node equivalent of `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`?

Tags: node.js, httpserver

The existence of these modules suggests Node does not ship with an equivalent command:

- https://www.npmjs.org/package/simplehttpserver
- https://www.npmjs.org/package/simple-http-server

Answer (score 16):

There is a node package to do this.

```
$ npm install http-server -g
$ http-server
```

Node isn't aggressively batteries included like python so you have to install the pieces you want explicitly.

Comment: Note that you can use `npx` to perform a [one-off invocation of a npm-hosted module without installing it](https://github.com/npm/npx#one-off-invocation-without-local-installation): simply run `$ npx http-server` in the command line.